# Position all the values in the horizontalwaterfall chart consistent on the one side

Tags: kendo-ui

is there a possibility to position the labels of positive and negative values in a horizontalwaterfall chart consistent on the one (right or left) side?

The positive values are positioned correctly with the option: `position: "outsideEnd"`

See my example here: http://dojo.telerik.com/Edojo/6

Thx in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

From kendo API for series.label.position ([more here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.labels.position))

> The position of the labels.
>
> "above" - the label is positioned at the top of the marker. **
>   Applicable for series that render points, incl. bubble. **
>
> "below" - the label is positioned at the bottom of the marker. **
>   Applicable for series that render points, incl. bubble. **
>
> "center" - the label is positioned at the point center. ** Applicable
>   for bar, column, donut, pie, funnel, radarColumn and waterfall series.
>   **
>
> "insideBase" - the label is positioned inside, near the base of the
>   bar. ** Applicable for bar, column and waterfall series. **
>
> "insideEnd" - the label is positioned inside, near the end of the
>   point. ** Applicable for bar, column, donut, pie, radarColumn and
>   waterfall series. **
>
> "left" - the label is positioned to the left of the marker. **
>   Applicable for series that render points, incl. bubble. **
>
> "outsideEnd" - the label is positioned outside, near the end of the
>   point. ** Applicable for bar, column, donut, pie, radarColumn and
>   waterfall series. Not applicable for stacked series.
>
> "right" - the label is positioned to the right of the marker. **
>   Applicable for series that render points, incl. bubble. **
>
> "top" - the label is positioned at the top of the segment. **
>   Applicable for funnel series **
>
> "bottom" - the label is positioned at the bottom of the segment. **
>   Applicable for funnel series **

Comment: I also read the documentation and tried all these options before. I hoped for an alternative posibility to position the labels...